# laptop won't shut down after updating

Tags: windows-8

The 2 of 22 update I had going took 1 complete day. The laptop then stated shutting down. This has been going for 24 hours and not shutting down. Just the message shutting down and wheel turning. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks working now after shutting down. It took a long time to update. Seems to be working fine after restart.

Answer (score 1):

If your PC doesnt say "Dont turn off the PC" or something like that, you can just hold the power button until it shuts down.

If it is still updating you can wait, but if it is really stuck for 24 hours, it is useless, just hold down the power button.

When it fails to boot or start up after you shut it down, Windows will likely start Windows Startup Repair if you have Win 8+ or you can start it by hand then.